# Image of $f(z)=\frac{z-3}{z-4}$ on $\{z\in\mathbb{C}|2<Re(z)<3\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|2<Re(z)<3\}$. Let $f(z)=\frac{z-3}{z-4}$. Find $f(D)$.

I thought of using the decomposition of Mobius transformations, i.e.

$$f_1(w)=w-4,\ f_2(w)=1/w,\ f_3(w)=1+w$$

Then we get

$$f(z)=\frac{z-3}{z-4}=\frac{z-4+1}{z-4}=1+\frac{1}{z-4}=f_3\Big(f_2\big(f_1(z)\big)\Big)$$

So $f(D)=f_3\Big(f_2\big(f_1(D)\big)\Big)$, and now we can deal with each transformation, i.e.

$$D_1=f_1(D)=\{z-4\in\mathbb{C}|2<Re(z)<3\}=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|-2<Re(z)<-1\}$$

And $f_3$ is similar to $f_1$. The problem is that I don't understand what the inversion $f_2$ will do on $D_1$.

Comment: I think it might be easier knowing some basic properties about mobius transformations in terms of "circles mapping on circles", "circles mapping on line" stuff. Plenty about that on the internet. In your case you are particularly interested what the lines $x=2$ and $x=3$ do with respect to the complex plane subject to $f(z)$. For that you can pick three random points on each line and calculate their function values. This is half the job...

Comment: $1/z$ is the composition of the plane inversion wrt the unit circle and the reflection wrt the real axis (aka conjugation). Consider where the inversion maps the vertical line $\operatorname {Re} z = a, a \neq 0$. The result is a circle; it's symmetric wrt the real axis; it goes through the origin; it goes through the point $1/a$. This uniquely defines the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $$w=\frac{z-3}{z-4}\implies z=\frac{4w-3}{w-1}$$

Now put $w=u+iv$ and simplify, so you get $$z=\frac{4u^2+4v^2-7u+3-iv}{(u-1)^2+v^2}$$

The region in question, $2<Re(z)<3$ becomes $$2<\frac{4u^2+4v^2-7u+3}{(u-1)^2+v^2}<3$$

The LHS simplifies to become $$(u-\frac 34)^2+v^2>\frac 74$$
The RHS simplifies to become $$(u-\frac 12)^2+v^2<\frac 14$$

Comment: WOW! thank you!

Comment: You are welcome